# R coda "The leading minor of order 3 is not positive definite"

Tags: r

Can someone explain to me what this error message means?

I have an MCMC sampling method called hitandrun (in unfinished package https://github.com/davidkane9/kmatching) that gives me a list of matrices which have columns as multivariate output of individual samples, here is an example of it in action:

```
> A = matrix(1, ncol = 3)
> b = 1
> ## gives me solutions of Ax = b (a.k.a x + y + z = 1)
> h = hitandrun(A,b, n=10, chains = 2)
> h
[[1]]
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]       [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]
[1,] 0.1804431 0.3340590 0.4195820 0.2061222 0.3591085 0.09984353 0.6707110 0.3926639 0.1283919
[2,] 0.6135745 0.4256909 0.3619727 0.2918238 0.5057426 0.81919629 0.2368842 0.1178713 0.2666737
[3,] 0.2059824 0.2402501 0.2184453 0.5020541 0.1351489 0.08096018 0.0924048 0.4894647 0.6049344
         [,10]
[1,] 0.1322112
[2,] 0.4736057
[3,] 0.3941831

[[2]]
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]       [,5]       [,6]      [,7]       [,8]      [,9]
[1,] 0.32883534 0.1284182 0.1735151 0.2005726 0.94511422 0.61653717 0.5130324 0.33228224 0.2088865
[2,] 0.65868549 0.3066952 0.5182009 0.3065610 0.01214334 0.07007548 0.1191157 0.01137002 0.3311197
[3,] 0.01247917 0.5648866 0.3082840 0.4928664 0.04274244 0.31338735 0.3678519 0.65634774 0.4599938
          [,10]
[1,] 0.61412223
[2,] 0.32289039
[3,] 0.06298738
```

I wanted to see the Gelman-Rubin diagnostic of this data, to see how much I need to thin it, but when I put it in function, I get an obscure error, and I don't know what it means. Here is that:

```
> mclist = lapply(h, function(x) mcmc(t(x), thin = 5))
> gelman.diag(mclist)
Error in chol.default(W) : 
  the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite
```

(I guess now it's order 1, but before it was order 3) Are there any coda experts on SO? I've tried to debug it, but it leads me to an internal function La_chol and I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: @ Mike: How did you get `hitandrun` function?

Comment: I wrote it. It is in an unfinished package. If you want to see it, it is located at: https://github.com/davidkane9/kmatching, @Metrics

Comment: Thanks; It would be better if you specify that in the question

Comment: The `hitandrun` function is irrelevant, since the entire matrix being fed to `mcmc()` is shown here.  I think the question is fine (so I upvoted it from -1 to 0) but probably better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm guessing it's referring to a function that performs a Cholesky decomposition, which requires a positive (semi?)definite matrix. This might be a multi-stage question, and the next stage could belong on Cross Validated or Mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be something wrong with getting the multivariate estimate of the Gelman-Rubin diagnostic. Setting `multivariate = FALSE` fixes the problem and outputs a single variable estimate for each variable. However, most of my variables are correlated because of the nature of the problem I am trying to solve, so I wonder (and hope) that this is giving me an overestimate of the diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem with my model - I found my matrix was not symmetrical, as it was an asymmetrical GRM matrix.  I used this function to make it symmetrical and the problem was solved (taken from [Most Efficient way to create a symmetric matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770004/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-symmetric-matrix/32770087#32770087)):

```
symmetrise <- function(mat){   rowscols <- which(lower.tri(mat), arr.ind=TRUE)   sparseMatrix(i=rowscols[,1], 
               j=rowscols[,2], 
               x=mat[lower.tri(mat)], 
               symmetric=TRUE, 
               dims=c(nrow(mat),ncol(mat)) )   }
```

This replicated the bottom left part to the top right part.